# How to find whether a 2D array (rectangular matrix) have a straight line

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I stumbled upon this problem while solving an algorithm question. There is a rectangular matrix.

[image: Sample Matrix]

I get a pair of positions as input, then how can I calculate if they fall in a straight line, for eg. in this case I get input as (d,B)(c,D)(b,F)(a,H) which infact is straight line.
If we see it carefully, the counter on the short side is jumping by 1 and counter on the longer side is jumping by 2. If I write my code based on this logic then, will it be a safe assumption for a bigger rectangles or I can face issue with that logic ?

I'm assuming here that inclined straight line can only be of two types
1) Where both the counters jump by 1, like the diagonal of a square matrix.
2) The case discussed above where counter is jumping by 1 on shorter side and by 2 on longer side.

Can there be a group of points that may fall in straight line but does not fit either of the above conditions and neither they are in a single row or a single column ?

Comment: This really depends on how these lines are defined. if they can be defined by only 2 or 3 points, you could probably define a large set of lines. For larger matrices you could probably find relation were there are jumps of 4 by 8 counter. So I think you should first find out(/know) which is the minimum amount of points which can make a line.

Comment: @GijsDenHollander - For checking whether the points are on the same line, we will require atleast 3 points on the line. So, the ratio of the counters may decide whether other points fall on that line. In this case the ratio of the counter is 1:2 and as you said for larger matrices it could be jump of 4 by 8 counter but that is also the ratio 1:2 only. So, by assuming 1:2 ratio of the counter it should solve this?

Comment: Another thing you have to pay attention to is if points can be used for multiple lines. And also if one point starts multiple lines, how are you going to  differentiate that?  Is 2:1 is also allowed? Apart from thinking of things I have mentioned here, I think you should be able to find al the lines in a matrix. But you need to be careful how you define which lines to count and which not to count especially for dens matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's start from two *degenerated cases*:

- if you have **0** points, answer as you wish (either there's a line, or there's no such line)
- if you have **1** or **2** points, the answer is always *yes*

Suppose, you have **3+** points and you want to check if they are all on the same line. Take two arbitrary points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`. Once again you have two cases:

- `x1 == x2`; check that all the points are such that `xi == x1`
- `x1 != x2`; check that all points are such that *two conditions* are met:

  ```
        (y1 - y2) * (xi - x2) == (yi - y2) * (x1 - x2)
  (y2*x1 - y1*x2) * (xi - x2) == (y2*xi - yi*x2) * (x1 - x2)
  ```

I.e. all points are on the same `y = kx + b` line where `k` and `b` are derived from `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`

In you case, when `A = 1, B = 2, ..., H = 8; a = 1, b = 2, ..., d = 4` we have

```
   (2, 4)
   (4, 3)
   (6, 2)
   (8, 1)
```

points which are on the same line. Possible (C#) implementation:

```
private static bool SameLine(IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> points) {
  if (null == points)
    return true;

  Tuple<int, int>[] data = points.ToArray();

  // i = 2 - first two points are always on the same line 
  for (int i = 2; i < data.Length; ++i) {
    int x1 = data[0].Item1;
    int y1 = data[0].Item2;

    int x2 = data[1].Item1;
    int y2 = data[1].Item2;

    int xi = data[i].Item1;
    int yi = data[i].Item2;

    // y = k * x + b where k = infinity
    if (x1 == x2) {
      if (xi != x1)
        return false;

      continue;
    }

    // Same k in y = k * x + b
    if (!((y1 - y2) * (xi - x2) == (yi - y2) * (x1 - x2)))
      return false;

    // Same b in y = k * x + b
    if (!((y2 * x1 - y1 * x2) * (xi - x2) == (y2 * xi - yi * x2) * (x1 - x2)))
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Test

```
  Tuple<int, int>[] test = new Tuple<int, int>[] {
    new Tuple<int, int>(2, 4),
    new Tuple<int, int>(4, 3),
    new Tuple<int, int>(6, 2),
    new Tuple<int, int>(8, 1),
  };

  // Same line
  Console.Write(SameLine(test) ? "Same line" : "different lines");
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I'm wondering how did you came up with those conditions ? Great work !!

Comment: @chitresh sirohi: there's only one line which contains two given points. A line can be represented as equation `y = k * x + b`. Two conditions are in fact the requirement that all pairs of the points define the same `k` and `b` (and thus the same line).